# Thrift TNonblockingServer EOF Exception

Tags: java, groovy, thrift

i have got server app written in java, and client app in groovy.
My server up get request and do sth. I use Thrift with TNonBlockingServer.

```
    public static void nonBlockingServer(HbaseLayerService.Processor processor) {
            try {
                final Integer serverPort = ConfigurationManager.instance().getServerPort();
                TNonblockingServerTransport serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(serverPort);
                TServer server = new TNonblockingServer(new TNonblockingServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));

                server.serve();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Throwables.propagate(e);
            }
        }
```

My client send ~100Mb data

```
TTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket('localhost', 12345, 100000))
transport.open()
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
HbaseLayerService.Client client = new HbaseLayerService.Client(protocol);
def putList = [] //~1500000 objects (string, string, string, int, byte[])
client.putEvent(new PutEventsOperation(putsToSend));
```

during this operation i have an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at communication_struct.thrift.HbaseLayerService$Client.recv_putEvent(HbaseLayerService.java:96)
```

This exception has type 4: **END_OF_FILE**.

With TSimpleServer everything is ok, but I want to take a few connections and do operation in queue in one thread.

Comment: this question is not about [thrift-protocol]. It is about transports.

Comment: "*~1500000 objects*"  -  [How large is the data block again?](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/7a8b286b3f03046a1b89f405129dbc042ddae818/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TIOStreamTransport.java)

Comment: it is not less than 50 mb and not more than 100mb

Comment: In that case I have no idea. But there are not so many places where END_OF_FILE. is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
In this particular case you should add new size to `TFramedTransport.Factory` as like below:

```
TServer server = new TNonblockingServer(new TNonblockingServer.Args(serverTransport)
                    .processor(processor)
                    .transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory(MAX_FRAMED_TRANSPORT_SIZE))
                    .protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory())
            );
```

The same operation should be done in client side:

```
TTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket('localhost', 12345), MAX_FRAMED_TRANSPORT_SIZE)
```

In my case `MAX_FRAMED_TRANSPORT_SIZE = 256 * 1024 * 1024`.

Comment: I looked at the wrong file. Instead of  trunk `lib/java` the link above goes to a commit from 2011. Back then there was no such CTOR (and in javame there is still none today). So yes, absolutely correct answer.